# My discord bot not sending welcome message when anyone join to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    const sohbet = await client.channels.cache.find(x => x.id == "801461330674057247")
    client.channels.get("801461330674057247").send("testing")
})
```

this is my code

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the ChannelText globally so that it can be reached anywhere in your script/app.

```
    var ChannelText = undefined;
    bot.on('ready', async () => {
        ChannelText = bot.channels.cache.get("801461330674057247");
        ChannelText.SendMessage("test test test!");
    });
    bot.on('guildMemberAdd', async () => {
        ChannelText.SendMessage("OH WOW IT'S WORKING!!! BUT CAN I GET THE USERNAME NOW?");
    });
```

Comment: Would appear you're using old API too. :)

Comment: that's not works..

Comment: C:\Users\ulaum\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Leet BOT\bot.js:36
    let ChannelText = DiscordClient.channels.cache.get("801461330674057247");
                      ^

ReferenceError: DiscordClient is not defined

Comment: Adjusted, you errored because you were copying the code and not adjusting anything. You will need to make changes to adapt the code, please don't copy/paste examples without learning.

Comment: uhm.. how can i download later edition :(

Comment: Sorry, was using my variables I hate calling clients; bots. The example should work correctly and if you have any issues check out discord.js basics; many setup guides with the emitters.

Comment: i'm not copy paster. i write this code with discord.js lessons and i'm i am workin' on it for 13-14 hours

Comment: Ahhh, old discord tutorials lurk you may need to reference how it's done with the latest libraries if searching the web.